# Eclipse: My files keep deleting themselves

Tags: java, eclipse, libgdx

While making my game i encountered an error where it said that file could not be found. After looking into it i found that it wasn't in the folder in desktop but displayed in the eclipse package explorer. After searching up i found a solution by linking the assets folder to the folder on the drive. This synced the folders but the my Fonts folder's content keeps deleting themselves. Whenever i re add them they get deleted. Before my other folders in my assets were getting deleting but after adding them back they stayed there. I cant figure out why my fonts folder keeps deleting itself. Any solution would be most welcome. If it helps i am creating a game using libgdx in java.
Thanks

EDIT: I tried to delete the actual fonts folder and add it again but when i deleted it, it deleted my sounds folder and when i created a new fonts folder it deleted my Backgrounds.Please Help

EDIT 2: Every time I re-add the folder and refresh in eclipse it deletes one of my other folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I linked the assets folder in my desktop application to the assets folder i my android application and Behold! It works;for now...